# Vercel build Error: ENOENT: no such file or director

Tags: vercel

Since a few day ago my builds cannot complete on Vercel.
It used to work perfectly fine, even when I try to redeploy previous builds or revert commits it logs the same error as the new one

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/builds/core/landing/web/.next/server/pages/404.html'
```

The issue seems to come the static directory .next.
My project is using node v14.21, I am aware it won't be supported anymore as of mid august on Vercel but it should not be a problem yet?

Did anyone of you encountered similar issue ?
Do you have any leads?

Thanks for you time